# change height in inches across 2 columns to numeric

Tags: r, dplyr

I have height in inches across 2 columns, for instance, 5'10. However, when I paste the values they turn into a character when I try to convert to string it turns to a list.

```
H8$height_feet <- transform(H8,height_feet = paste(H8$Height_1_TEXT, H8$Height_2_TEXT, sep = "."))
H8$height_feet <- apply(H8$height_feet, 2, as.numeric)

# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Height_1_TEXT Height_2_TEXT
          <dbl>         <dbl>
1             5             5
2             5            10
3             5             6
4             5             2
5             5             6
6             6             0
```

Ideally, this would be converted into a column that is numeric with 5.5 being the first value, however, this can be done with sapply, but 5.10 becomes 5.1 which is inaccurate.

Comment: `H8$height_feet <- H8$Height_1_TEXT + H8$Height_2_TEXT / 12`

Comment: @AndrewGustar it is a good idea, but it is slightly off for instance, 5'10 becomes  5.833333

Comment: @Lowpar - 5'10" is 5 and 10/12ths, or 5.83333.

Comment: @AndrewGustar, wow sorry man, it works perfectly.